Maven how to do autobuilding/autocompilation in IDEA
I will describe the problem and what I did to solve it.
I'm moving from gradle to maven (looking for a job, lol) and I'm faced with the fact that when I run a program in idea with maven (manually using the idea tools, click on the green triangle), the program compiles only once and only the first time there is correct output to the console . Next, I change the code - run the program - and get the previous output.
The command mvn clean\build\package solves this
This apparently recompiles the program and I get the correct output.
It is very uncomfortable. Googling gave such options as setting the build project automaticaly flag in setting - compiller - done, no result
For example, I, who was used to working in gradle, where there were no such problems, still worked adequately there, I write the code, change it, ctrl - shift - f10 - the program restarts with the latest data. This looks crazy, obviously some kind of mistake.
This is my pom file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>org.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>untitled4</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


     <properties>
         <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>



     <dependencies>

     </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>17</source>
                     <target>17</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
     </build>

</project>

By the way, I found a solution to run the project from the command line, it’s more than doing gradle installDist in gradle, but it’s like this
.DEFAULT_GOAL := build-run

start:
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.Main"

.PHONY: build

Need help setting up autobuilding on maven, thanks
(below is a screenshot that shows that the output of the program is not current)

I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side. New code is executed in my test maven project. Could you please share screenshot from "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner"? Is it reproducible with new sample project?
